# tool to quickly check how many sectors there are on a external Hard drive - specifically an Ipod - preferably on windows

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, disk-utility

I've got an old ipod with bad sectors that i'm trying to format with error checking. At this point of time, i'm convinced that its checked more sectors than there are, and the check has been ACTIVELY going on for over a month.

I have another, identical, refurbed ipod that works - i've tried getting data about it using hdtune - which claims its a 19 gb hard drive, and refuses to do any checks on it. Any free, quick way to just check the sector count that'll work on an ipod?

Comment: If you can enable hard disk mode on the iPod, you could get away (on Windows 7 at any rate) with a `CHKDSK /R`.

Comment: chkdsk /R dosen't work on ipods from what i can tell. i don't actually need to format the second one too, that would be a very, very bad thing

Comment: Well it was worth a shot.